# Combining wildcard command along with %s in where clause statement for ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, search, where-clause, wildcard

I am trying to write a script where the user can search for a five digit zipcode using an input statement and a search cursor. The zipcodes in the file though are nine characters long (i.e. xxxxx-xxxx) so I'm trying to use the wildcard character after five digits in the where clause  but I can't figure out either where to put it or the syntax I'm supposed to use. Currently I can get the use input zipcode to print out but when I try putting the % wildcard in I get an error. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code so far:

```
import arcpy


#set workspace
work=raw_input("work= ")
arcpy.env.workspace=work
zip5=input("zip5= ")
strZip= str(zip5)

def searchHospitals(work,zip5):
    fc= "Hospital.shp"
    whereClause= '"ZIPCODE" LIKE'+"'%s'"% strZip
    print whereClause
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use format instead, since % is probably your wildcard character.

```
def searchHospitals(work,strZip):
    fc= "Hospital.shp"
    whereClause= '"ZIPCODE" LIKE'+"'{0}%'".format(strZip)
```

But you can also use double percent signs (%%) in your method:

```
def searchHospitals(work,strZip):
    fc= "Hospital.shp"
    whereClause= '"ZIPCODE" LIKE'+"'%s%%'"% strZip
```