# What is the right SQL query for this case?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, sql, python-script-tool

I want to use input string in part of the SQL query, and the code has been posted below.

```
import arcpy
import os

in_features = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
target_county = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
out_path = os.path.dirname(in_features)
out_name= "%s.shp" % target_county
where_clause=""""CNTY_NM" = %s""" % target_county
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features, out_path, out_name, where_clause)
```

When I run the script, it gives the error.
[image]
[image]

I don't know what is wrong with the code. Any suggestions?

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 Desktop Advanced License.

Comment: What is the full error message including line number?  Can you always supply error messages as text rather than pictures, please?

Comment: Sorry about that. I will learn how to show error message with the code.

Comment: See also [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155820/how-do-i-combine-a-wildcard-command-along-with-s-in-a-where-clause-statement) which also constructs a where clause including wildcards.

Comment: All you need to do is click in that results window and Ctrl-A, then Ctrl-C then Ctrl-V to select all, copy and paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [a SQL where clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp), single quotes (`"FIELD" = 'provided_value'`) are needed around the match string in the where clause. You are missing the single quotes around the provided value. It should be like this:

```
where_clause="\"CNTY_NM\" = '%s'" % target_county
```