# SelectLayerByAttribute() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, update, syntax

I am trying to update a field with a new value as I updated a Domain for a web purpose.  I am new to this.

I want be able to choose the layer and then the field to update

```
M=Municipal
S=State
C=County
P=Private
```

Here is the script so far.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Ownership Domain Update.py
# Created on: 2016-11-15 11:57:22.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Usage: Ownership Domain Update <FClass>
# Description:
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
FClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
FieldName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# Process: Select Municipal
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(FClass, "NEW_SELECTION", FieldName  = 'M')

# Process: Calculate Municipal
arcpy.CalculateFieldName_management(FClass, FieldName , "\"Municipal\"", "VB", "")

# Process: Select State
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(FClass, "NEW_SELECTION", FieldName  = 'S')

# Process: Calculate State
arcpy.CalculateFieldName_management(FClass, FieldName , "\"State\"", "VB", "")

# Process: Select County
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(FClass, "NEW_SELECTION", FieldName  = 'C')
# Process: Calculate County
arcpy.CalculateFieldName_management(FClass, FieldName , "\"County\"", "VB", "")

# Process: Select Private
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(FClass, "NEW_SELECTION", FieldName  = 'P')

# Process: Calculate Private
arcpy.CalculateFieldName_management(FClass, FieldName , "\"Private\"", "VB", "")

# Process: Clear
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(FClass, "CLEAR_SELECTION", FieldName  = 'P')
```

And the Error:

```
ERROR:
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\_LSSE GIS Toolbox\_LSSE Toolbox\Ownership Domain Update.py", line 18, in <module>
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(FClass, "NEW_SELECTION", FieldName  = 'M')
TypeError: SelectLayerByAttribute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'FieldName'

Failed to execute (Script).
Failed at Tue Nov 15 14:14:33 2016 (Elapsed Time: 0.06 seconds)
```

Comment: You need to enclose the sql queries, for example  Fieldname='M', in " or ' signs, check out help section for the tool

Answer (score 1):

```
# Process: Select Municipal
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(FClass, "NEW_SELECTION", "FieldName  = 'M'")
```

BERA is correct, your SQL statement needs to be a string like I have adjusted above. Because your "FieldName" is a variable, you will probably need do it like this:

```
# Process: Select Municipal
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(FClass, "NEW_SELECTION", "{0}  = 'M'".format(FieldName))
```

The .format is just a way to substitute your value into a string, you can use as many substitutions as you want in one string, the number in the brackets indicates the position for each, so you could do something like this:

```
var1 = "Hello"
var2 = "!"
"{0} world{1}".format(var1, var2)
```

It's a handy trick that I use a lot in my scripting

Comment: @GeoSharp I see that in the examples ESRI has on the select by location help page you are correct, but interestingly I have never done that in my scripts and I've never had problems... Does it really make a difference? Or do you think the need for them was eliminated by some clever ESRI scripting at some point?

Answer (score 0):

Your entire where clause needs to be surrounded by quotations either `""` or `''`. Within the where clause, your criteria need to be surrounded by the correct syntax quotations. The correct syntax is `''` for the criteria. Like this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("GNSS_Results_Stations", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"FieldName\" = 'M'")
```

Because the criteria of the where clause should be surrounded by `''` it is easiest to use `""` for the entire where clause.

Some parsers also require that the field name be surrounded by the correct syntax quotations, `""` for fields (as shown above). However I don't believe this to be the case when using `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management`. For more specifics on that arcpy command you can review the documentation [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm). For more information on how to structure the where clause see this GIS Stack Exchange question and answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217232/what-is-the-right-sql-query-for-this-case/217233#217233).

Additionally you probably should use a more descriptive variable or formatted differently variable name than `FieldName`. I don't think it is a keyword but to avoid confusion often times python variables are designated with only lower case and separated by an underscore, e.g. `field_name`.